# Trac packages not properly installed

Tags: python, trac

I am checking in a RedHat server to see if there is a trac installation, the trac-admin is not in the /usr/bin(is nowhere to be found). In the /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ there are no trac packages at all, but i found the following paths with a trac directory in them:

```
/root/.cpan/build/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0-1/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/python/tests/trac
/root/.cpan/build/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0-0/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/python/tests/trac
/opt2/trac
```

These directories show the following:

```
__init__.py  test.py  versioncontrol
```

and the /opt/trac is the environment of the trac:

```
conf  db  files  htdocs  log  plugins  README  templates  trac_banner.png  VERSION
```

Does this mean that the trac is installed? Can I just delete those directories and try a new installation?

Answer (score 1):

The directories you found under `/root/.cpan` do not indicate that Trac is installed. The presence of a Trac environment at `/opt/trac` is the important find. Please make a backup of that directory at least, and preferably a backup of the entire server, before proceeding.

To check if Trac is installed, start a python 2.x interpreter session and see if `import trac` succeeds. If it does not, Trac is not installed for that Python interpreter. It's possible you have other instances of Python installed. If Python 3 is your default you may need to run `python2` to start the interpreter.

I would copy `/opt/trac` to my local machine and create a new Trac 1.2.2 installation. You probably don't know the version of Trac that was used with `/opt/trac`. You could determine that by inspecting the database, but it's easier to just create a new Trac installation for that Trac environment and upgrade the environment when prompted. If that goes well you can do the same on your remote server.

I'm assuming you are using SQLite, in which case the database will be `/opt/trac/db/trac.db`. Check the `[trac]` `database` string in `/opt/trac/conf/trac.ini` to determine if you are using SQLite. If your Trac environment uses MySQL or PostgreSQL you'll need to copy the database to your local machine to test the upgrade process.

Suggested reading is [TracInstall](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall) and [TracUpgrade](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUpgrade).